# How to remove stubborn adhesive residue from my windows?

Tags: windows, cleaning, adhesive, vinyl

This sounds ridiculous but I was Googling forever to no avail.

We have been scrubbing like mad for four years with all purpose cleaner.

I’m not sure what kind of product to use to clean or clean off the adhesive that’s trimming all of our vinyl windows at the window-sill interface (*we had these windows installed in 2016 and no amount of elbow grease has helped*).

[image: picture of the sill adhesive in question]

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: You taking aboutthat caulked joint?

Comment: i hate to tell you this, but when all the stars wink out and die, then forever will just be starting

Comment: Are you talking about that band of off-white caulk between the horizontal and vertical?  Maybe you can drop your photo into Paint and circle the area that troubles you.  It’s SE tradition that a rough mouse-drawn circle, in red, automatically gets you a +1 (true fact)!

Answer (score 1):

Four years ? Your arm must be very tired and muscular. How did you find time to google forever?

Try [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/).

You need a [razor window/glass scraper](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=glass%20razor%20scraper&t=ffcm&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fimages-na.ssl-images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F41UCVWH8tJL._SY300_QL70_.jpg).

[image]

Use the scraper and some denatured alcohol, apply a little denatured alcohol before hand to soften it up then scrape it and  wipe with the denatured alcohol, Repeat.

You may need to CAREFULLY clean the blade with some denatured alcohol between scrapings.

Comment: For some sticky stuff, orange oil (limonene) works better for cleanup than denatured alcohol.